An "almost" geodesic dome
A regular $ n$-gon is inscribed in the unit circle centered in $0$.
We want to build an "almost" geodesic dome upon it this way: on each side of the $n$-gon we build an equilateral triangle whose dihedral angle with the $n$-gon is such that the distance from $0$ of the upper vertex's projection on the unit circle plane is $(1-1/n)$; over this "first floor" we connect all the upper vertices and we have a new smaller $n$-gon inscribed in the circle with radius $(1-1/n)$, so we repeat the process and this time the distance from $0$ of the upper vertices' projection on the unit circle plane is $(1-2/n)$ and so on.
If the limit $n \rightarrow \infty$, which function fits the border of the dome? What is the maximum height?
I tried to solve this way: $n$ fixed and $r < n$, each upper vertex coordinate is
$$ \left( \frac {r+1}{n}, \sum_{m=0}^r \sqrt{ \left( \sqrt{3}\left(1-\frac mn\right)^2 \sin\left(\frac\pi n\right) \right)^2-\frac1{n^2}} \, \right)$$
With $n = 100 $ this is the plot made with Mathematica, but I wasn't able to find that function


Under the square root, do you have $1-\dfrac m{n}$ to the second or fourth power?

@IosifPinelis to the fourth power, because it's the hypothenuse squared. Thank you for your answer, I'm reading it. Do you think the expression I found is right?

I will have to correct the answer then, when I have a chance.

So at a typical vertex, six triangles meet, but at the one vertex at the center, $n$ triangles meet.

I cannot follow your informal description. In particular, what is "each upper vertex"? What is "each upper vertex coordinate"? It seems that you have two coordinates --  how are they defined, exactly? What is $r$? What do you mean by "function [that] fits the border of the dome"? Etc., etc.

I think I have now understood your derivation. In particular, it appears that $\frac{r+1}n$ is the distance of the projection of the new vertex after round $r=0,1,\dots$ from the circle. However, of course you should have $1-m/n$  instead of $(1-m/n)^2$. To quickly see why this is true, use a circle of radius $R$ (say centimeters) rather than $1$, and then check the physical dimensions of the terms.

The expression
$$f_n(x):=\sqrt{\Big(\sqrt{3}\Big(1-\dfrac x{n}\Big) \sin\dfrac \pi{n} \Big)^2-\dfrac1{n^2}}$$
is defined for real $x\ge0$ iff
$$x\le x_n:=n\Big(1-\frac1{a_n\sqrt3}\Big),$$
where $a_n:=n\sin\frac\pi n\to\pi$ (as $n\to\infty$). Also, the function $f_n$ is decreasing on the interval $[0,x_n]$. So, $0\le f_n\le f_n(0)=O(1/n)$. So, the sum, $\sum_{m=0}^r f_n(m)$ (corrected according to my comment),
in your displayed expression differs from the integral
$$I(n,r):=\int_0^r f_n(x)\,dx$$
for integers $r\in[0,x_n]$ only by $O(1/n)$.
Using the substitution $v=(1-x/n)a_n\sqrt3$, we get
$$I(n,r)=\frac1{a_n\sqrt3}\int_{(1-r/n)a_n\sqrt3}^{a_n\sqrt3}\sqrt{v^2-1}\,dv \\
=\frac{G(a_n\sqrt3)-G((1-r/n)a_n\sqrt3)}{a_n\sqrt3},$$
where
$$G(v):=\frac{1}{2} v \sqrt{v^2-1}-\ln
   \left(\sqrt{v-1}+\sqrt{v+1}\right),$$
an anti-derivative of $\sqrt{v^2-1}$.
It follows that, for each
$$t\in(0,T),\quad \text{where }T:=1-\frac1{\pi\sqrt3},$$
the vertex $(\frac{r+1}n,\sum_{m=0}^r f_n(m))$ tends to
$$(t,F(t))$$
as $n\to\infty$ and $r/n\to t$, where
$$F(t):=\frac{G(\pi\sqrt3)-G((1-t)\pi\sqrt3)}{\pi\sqrt3}.$$
Here is the graph $\{(t,F(t))\colon0<t<T\}$:


Thanks for your detailed answer, I need to say that I found $ T:=1-\frac1{\pi\sqrt[4]{3}} $, so the profile is different. Am I wrong?

@user967210 : Yes, your expression is incorrect -- my previous comment.

You are completely right! I don't know how that exponent came out! Thank you

I have simplified the derivation (and also the expression) of $F(t)$. Please let me know if you have further questions or concerns.

Thank you so much. I have one last question: I found that the maximum height of the dome has this closed form $ \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3\pi^2-1}+\frac{\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}-3\pi}{\sqrt{9\pi^2-3}}\right)}{\sqrt{3}\pi} $. Is there a closed form for the profile length?

@user967210 : I think so. The length of the limit curve will be $\int_a^b\sqrt{1+F'(t)^2},dt$ for some $a$ and $b$. So, you will have to integrate something like $\sqrt{A+Bv^2}$ in $v$, which is expressed in elementary functions.
